# xamarin ios maps annotation open new scene

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, annotations, xamarin, maps

I need to create an app where when an annotation is clicked, the app opens a new scene from a storyboard
but when I try to open a new scene, xamarin gives an error. Here is the relevant code:

```
class MyMapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
    {
        string pId = "PinAnnotation";

        public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
        { 

            // create pin annotation view
            MKAnnotationView pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView)mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation (pId);

            if (pinView == null)
                pinView = new MKPinAnnotationView (annotation, pId);

            ((MKPinAnnotationView)pinView).PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green;
            pinView.CanShowCallout = true;
            pinView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
            Console.WriteLine ("anotation view");
            return pinView;
        }

        public override void CalloutAccessoryControlTapped (MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView view, UIControl control)
        {

            AboutPodnik aboutPodnik = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("AboutPodnik") as AboutPodnik; //cannot acces non-static member
            NavigationController.PushViewController (aboutPodnik, true); //cannot acces non-static member
        }
    }
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController' via nested type `Projekt.Mapa.MyMapDelegate'
```

Comment: Please include the error you get.

Comment: http://www.fastimages.eu/?v=screenzzz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you do not have access to the Storyboard object you want in the map view delegate because you are outside of your view controller, so you have to somehow return the "tap" to the view controller context. Here's one way to do that:

In your `MyMapDelegate` class:

```
class MyMapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public event EventHandler AnnotationTapped;

    public override void CalloutAccessoryControlTapped(MKMapView mapView, MKAnootationView view, UIControl control)
    {
        if (AnnotationTapped != null) {
            AnnotationTapped(view, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your view controller:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var mapViewDelegate = new MyMapDelegate();
    mapViewDelegate.AnnotationTapped += TheMapView_OnAnnotationTapped;

    // Replace 'TheMapView' with whatever your MKMapView control is named
    TheMapView.Delegate = mapViewDelegate;
}

private void TheMapView_OnAnnotationTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    AboutPodnik aboutPodnik = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("AboutPodnik") as AboutPodnik;
    NavigationController.PushViewController (aboutPodnik, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks but in 
NavigationController.PushViewController (aboutPodnik, true);
I have this :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Which part of that line is null when run? NavigationController? aboutPodnik?

Comment: I'm guessing that means NavigationController is null then. Do you have that view controller coming from a navigation controller on your storyboard?

Comment: I have in root view tab controller and as tab is ios maps